# Get the api reference of a library without leaving the IDE?

Tags: api, ide, documentation

I wonder if there's a way to get a list of classes, constants and functions in a library without going through the code of that library? I don't mean something like intellisense, because it doesn't give you an overall view of the library, it just tells you how you can proceed from the first things you've typed in. I mean something like [this](https://pub.dev/documentation/english_words/latest/english_words/english_words-library.html).

I always import a library and then search for a summary of its API in its documentation page, but since I'm not a pro, I'm afraid I've been taking the dumb way the whole time. So I suspect there should/might be a faster way for getting this summary without leaving the IDE?

(Although I'm using VSCode as my IDE [and I'd be happy too if your answer is based on VSCode], this question might have a more generic solution which I'm unaware of, and thus not tagging it merely as a VSCode specific question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a VSCode-specific answer to this question [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_go-to-symbol). First ctrl+click (or F12: Go to Definition) on the imported library to open its code. Then:

> You can **navigate symbols inside a file with **Ctrl+Shift+O. By typing : the symbols will be grouped by category**. Press Up or Down and navigate to the place you want.